# Octopress 'rake aborted' during 'rake install' on Windows 10

Tags: ruby, windows, octopress

Today I tried to get octopress running on Windows and everything worked fine until `rake install` because then I got this message:

```
C:\octopress>rake install --trace
## Set the codepage to 65001 for Windows machines
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - chcp 65001
C:/octopress/Rakefile:32:in ``'
C:/octopress/Rakefile:32:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby21/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby21/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

I have already tried reinstalling the gems, running it as administrator and as a normal user.  Has anybody else had the same problem while trying to install octopress under Windows 10?

**Edit://** I found out that the error simply belongs to the command 'chcp' which is not avaiable on Windows 10 x64. Is there any way to get this command working on Windows 10 x64?

Comment: Color me confused. Pretty sure it is available.

Comment: Today i upgradet Windows 10 to the newest build now the command is avaiable.

Comment: How do you solve the problem at last?

Comment: @Jaskey The upgrade of Windows 10 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An upgrade of Windows 10 to the newest build solved the problem.